# Good example of how to build an iphone app that integrates with facebook

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I have experience building iPhone applications, however I'm new to the facebook API for iOS. Does anyone know of a good example of an iOS app that will post to user's facebook wall? I'm trying to integrate this functionality into an existing app that I'm working on. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the following open-source project:

[facebook-ios-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)

It's an open-source library to let you post to Facebook from your own iOS app.

Comment: Hey Brad, I've actually seen this before. It's helpful, but there's one problem with it: To grant access that API uses the iPhone 4's fast-app-switching feature, which basically backgrounds my app and loads either safari or the FBApp to grant access to my application. Is there any way to grant facebook access without backgrounding the application?

Answer (score 0):

They have posted code for a sample ViewController here as well.  Unfortunately this doesn't do an explicit wall update, but it does read the users' status and request them to log in.  And underneath this you can retrieve the source for the entire demo application:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/sample/DemoApp/Classes/DemoAppViewController.m#L79

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/DemoApp

Answer (score 0):

You can check our documentation for iOS SDK 3.0.8 here at
https://developers.facebook.com/ios/
Download the SDK package here at
https://github.com/downloads/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/FacebookSDK-3.0.8.pkg
Then try the samples/ folder for the existing samples. 
Specially you can look at Scrumptuous and Hackbook for latest examples.